# SharePoint 2013 display usage reports for custom events

Tags: custom-actions, usage-counters

I created custom usage event type and button described on this page:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715889.aspx

Everything is working fine - I can find logs files with this event activity but I cannot find Usage Report (excel file) for this event in SharePoint. I can only display Usage Report for View event. Is there any possibility to display report for my custom event ?